# How to better display the data using ComplexListPlot?

Tags: plotting, function-construction, complex

I'm trying to plot the solution of the equation with ComplexListPlot but the plot of the data points are small and hard to see. 
Do you have any idea to display it better and easier to see the data?

```
sol = NSolve[(6666.666666666667` T + 
      s (10.` + 200.` T + s (11.` + s + 10.` T + s (11.` + s) T))) == 
    0, s];
{s1, s2, s3, s4} = s /. sol;
lower = 1;
upper = 10000;
step = 1;
data1 = Table[s1, {T, lower, upper, step}];
data2 = Table[s2, {T, lower, upper, step}];
data3 = Table[s3, {T, lower, upper, step}];
data4 = Table[s4, {T, lower, upper, step}];
ComplexListPlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> {"s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"}]
```

[image]

My real goal is to find T so the equation has two negative real roots (any values and not too near the y axes) and two conjugated roots which is equal or close to `0.31 ± 4.14I` so it would also be great if you have any idea to do that. I planned to plot the roots with different T and then looking at the graph to pick T but it doesn't seem good.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you have any idea to display it better and easier to see the data

One option is to use `PlotStyle` and change the point size?

```
ComplexListPlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[.02], PlotLegends -> {"s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"},
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could also use Manipulate to change the plotRange in order to zoom in more easily into the area of interest in the plot.

Here is an example

```
Manipulate[
 ComplexListPlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[.02], 
  PlotLegends -> {"s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  PlotRange -> {{fromX, toX}, {fromY, toY}}],
 {{fromX, -11, "starting x"}, -30, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{toX, 6, "ending x"}, 1, 30, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{fromY, -7, "starting y"}, -10, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{toY, 7, "ending y"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {fromX, toX, fromY, toY}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are also few `ResourceFunctions` now that makes zooming easier for plots, but I did not find one that worked for your plot. May be someone knows one.

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/search/?i=zoom+

[image]